# Problem configuring tusd over https on Nginx

Tags: nginx, https, transloadit, tus

I am trying to setup tusd with Uppy on https without success. It works well on http.

Here's my nginx conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen[::]: 80;
  server_name
  DOMAIN.com
  www.DOMAIN.com;

  root / srv / users / DOMAIN / apps / DOMAIN / public;

  access_log / srv / users / DOMAIN / log / DOMAIN / DOMAIN_nginx.access.log main;
  error_log / srv / users / DOMAIN / log / DOMAIN / DOMAIN_nginx.error.log;

  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X - Real - IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X - Forwarded - For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  include / etc / nginx - sp / vhosts.d / DOMAIN.d
  /*.nonssl_conf;
      include /etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/DOMAIN.d/*.conf;
  }

  server {
      listen       443 ssl http2;
      listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
      server_name
          DOMAIN.com
          www.DOMAIN.com
        ;

      ssl_certificate_key      ssl/DOMAIN.key;
      ssl_certificate          ssl/DOMAIN.combined_crt;

      root   /srv/users/DOMAIN/apps/DOMAIN/public;

      access_log  /srv/users/DOMAIN/log/DOMAIN/DOMAIN_nginx.access_ssl.log  main;
      error_log  /srv/users/DOMAIN/log/DOMAIN/DOMAIN_nginx.error_ssl.log;

      proxy_set_header    Host              $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-SSL   on;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      include /etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/DOMAIN.d/*.ssl_conf;
      include /etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/DOMAIN.d/*.conf;


  location /files/ {
        #resolver 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2;

        proxy_pass  http://localhost:3020/files;   
        proxy_set_header Host $host; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;    

        # Disable request and response buffering    
        proxy_request_buffering  off;               
        proxy_buffering          off;                
        proxy_http_version       1.1;                 

        # Add X-Forwarded-* headers so that response can reference https and
        # originating host:port                                                     
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $hostname;                       
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                                
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;      
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;            

        # Allow proxying of websockets if required               
        proxy_set_header         Upgrade $http_upgrade;         
        proxy_set_header         Connection "upgrade";        
        client_max_body_size     0;  
    }
  }
```

At another conf file I have this additional configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass      $backend_protocol://$backend_host:$backend_port;
}
```

At Chrome console I have the following output:

```
upload.js:2 OPTIONS https://DOMAIN/files/2b775a112504ed1222c6ffdd4fbdac03+Dc99JI0Zvgh54FXVfpp5K32GAiZBjV5bY-d9tzj8fDL1FxNKKZrHP_SBE6OERG8SWAm1ZjqtjYMVWSvWCQLba0qsR8krfVBYw8ApHqIBO7DG9Bn1t_tv_a6nuuTuqlXC net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Notice the domain without the .com extension!

I tried all combinations of configuration, commenting the configuration lines without success. Can you spot the mistake?

Comment: What are used values for variables `$backend_protocol://$backend_host:$backend_port;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contractor solved it for me and the solution is neat. He did it instead configuring Apache.

At the first nginx conf file he removed the "location /files/" section entirely. At the apache conf file, he added the following lines:

```
    ProxyPass /files http://localhost:3020/files
    ProxyPassReverse /files http://localhost:3020/files
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty clearly a network issue which should be a definite mismatch between the data that is advertised in the HTTP Headers and the data transferred over the wire.

**It could come from the following:**

1. **Server**: If a server has a bug with certain modules that changes the content but don't update the content-length in the header or just doesn't work properly. It was the case for the Node HTTP Proxy at some point (see [here](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/623))
2. **Proxy**: Any proxy between you and your server could be modifying the request and not update the content-length header.

This problem could also be the nginx docker container disk space. Just check and if full please clear the files.

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Re-use then adapt (from `companion.mywebsite.com` to `yourdomain.com`) this working `nginx` configuration file :

*( don't forget to change also `ssl_certificate`, `ssl_certificate_key` and `ssl_dhparam` )*

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        server_name  companion.mywebsite.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3020;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/companion.mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/companion.mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


    server {
    if ($host = companion.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  companion.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}}
```

Then try again...  if you get this error:

```
Nginx Error: The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.
```

Run:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

To fix permission then restart `apache`